# Overriding Mobile SDK 7.3 login screen for React Native

Tags: oauth2, connected-apps, mobilesdk, react-native

we are doing a custom development of a mobile app connected to SF with a connected App. I was wondering if there's any way to override the default salesforce login screen that pops up and use a view of the application as a login. If that's not possible, can you somehow override the login page where you are redirected? If there is, will this impact the ORG login screen as well?

The users will be prompted with the login as soon as they open the app, we didn't change the login flow. The app is for managing events and activities for each of the org users that have access to the connected app.

It's mostly for styling matters and keeping a coherent experience throughout the whole of it.

Comment: What login flow are you using? What is the expected end to end experience? When a user opens up your app are they immediately presented with a login screen? Is that screen for SF or for your own custom server? At what point in your process do users log into Salesforce?

Comment: Yes, the users will be prompted with the login as soon as they open the app, and that login is for SF. The app is for managing events and activities for each of the org users that have access to the connected app.

Comment: Are these internal or external users?

Comment: Internal users, they would use the same credentials to log in to the app and the org